# Random enemy pattern

Tags: c#, random, xna-4.0, monogame

I wanna a pattern who move my enemy randomly at all because when i have 3 or 4 enemys they seem like the same enemy movement.
this is my code for the random  :

```
            int seed = unchecked(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode());
         rand = new Random(seed);
```

And here the code for process the move:

```
   public  void move(GameTime time, WorldScreen screen)
    {
        timer += (float)time.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (timer > 2000)
        {
            switch (rand.Next(0, 3))
            {
                case 0:
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.down;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.right;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.left;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.up;
                    break;

            }
            timer = 0;
        }
        timer1 += (float)time.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (timer1 > 50)
        {
            timer1 = 0;
            if (direction == Enemy.Direction.down)
            {
                if (!MoveCollision(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y + speed), screen))
                {
                    base.position.Y += speed;
                    ActualAnimation = getAnimation("rundown");
                }
                else
                {
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.right;
                }
            }
            if (direction == Enemy.Direction.up)
            {
                if (!MoveCollision(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y - speed), screen))
                {
                    base.position.Y -= speed;
                    ActualAnimation = getAnimation("runup");
                }
                else
                {
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.down;
                }
            }
            if (direction == Enemy.Direction.right)
            {
                if (!MoveCollision(new Vector2(position.X + speed, position.Y), screen))
                {
                    base.position.X += speed;
                    ActualAnimation = getAnimation("runright");
                }
                else
                {
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.left;
                }
            }
            if (direction == Enemy.Direction.left)
            {
                if (!MoveCollision(new Vector2(position.X - speed, position.Y), screen))
                {
                    base.position.X -= speed;
                    ActualAnimation = getAnimation("runleft");
                }
                else
                {
                    base.direction = Enemy.Direction.up;
                }

            }
        }
        ActualAnimation.update(time, position);
    }
```

but this code just do the same pattern for all enemys on the room.
thx for help me with it .

Comment: Where is the `rand = new Random(seed)` line?

Comment: You might find it useful to change `rand.Next(0, 3)` to `rand.Next(0, 4)` as the second parameter is an **exclusive** upper bound. In other words `rand.Next(0, 3)` only returns values from `{ 0, 1, 2 }`.

Comment: Can you try instantiating a single `new Random()` (without the unnecessary seed code) as a `static` field?

Comment: for some enemys i think this didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I belive the problem lays on this

```
int seed = unchecked(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode()); rand = new Random(seed);`
```

Check if you are calling it multiple times too close in time. If thats so you'll get the same random number on

```
rand.Next(0, 3)
```

Every time you call it, you'll get the same number, therefore you'll get the same pattern on every enemy.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solve this one putting a counter on the for reader for do the seed like this (this is on the for map reader) :

```
int id = map.Layers[1].Tiles[i].Gid;
            if (id == 172)
            {
                enemys.Add(new Hero.World.Entitys.Enemys.Octorock(new Vector2((int)position.X + map.Layers[1].Tiles[i].X * 16, (int)position.Y + map.Layers[1].Tiles[i].Y * 16),i));

            }
```

And after that for the constructor of the enemy something like this :

```
    public Octorock(Vector2 position,int i) :base(position)
    {
        int seed = unchecked(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
         rand = new Random(seed*i);}
```